# Notify JIRA once Spreadsheet is edited

Tags: google-sheets, automation, jira

I have two columns in a Google Spreadsheet

A is the list of tasks and
B has the SLA dates for each task.

These tasks are also JIRA tasks for our Designer.

What I would like to do is to automatically update the due date to a JIRA task once I the date is added/edited in the Spreadsheet. Would that be possible? Even if I could do that the other way round (update the Spreadsheet from JIRA), might be useful.

Any thoughts on this much appreciated!